# Send image source path from C++ to QML in a cross platform way

Tags: c++, qt, qml

#### Working code

This code shows the image correctly:

```
Image {
    source: Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + "C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sli\\3d.png")
}
```

#### Bad code

This code is *not* working, I mean the image is not shown:

```
Image {
    source: Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + cpplib.path + "\\" + "3d.png")
}
```

#### QML log of path

Logging `path` on QML:

```
console.log(cpplib.path)
```

```
C:\Users\m3\AppData\Local\Temp\sli
```

#### C++ log of path

Logging `path` on C++:

```cpp
QString path = // ...
qDebug() << path;
```

```
"C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sli"
```

---

How can I send image source path from C++ to QML in a **cross platform** way?

### UPDATE

Logging the image source by:

```
Image {
    // ...
    onSourceChanged: {
        console.log("image source:", source)
    }
}
```

results in:

```
qml: image source: file:///C:/Users/m3/AppData/Local/Temp/sli/3d.png
```

### UPDATE

I set the image source consecutively:

```
imageID.source = Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + cpplib.path + "\\3d.png")
imageID.source = Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + "C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sli\\3d.png")
```

To my surprise, the logs inside `onSourceChanged` show the two are actually the same:

```
    onSourceChanged: {
        console.log("image source:", source)
    }
```

```
qml: image source: file:///C:/Users/m3/AppData/Local/Temp/sli/3d.png
qml: image source: file:///C:/Users/m3/AppData/Local/Temp/sli/3d.png
```

Comment: Did you try forward slashes `/`?

Comment: @Taron Yes, I tried.

Comment: maybe you set `cpplib.path` after the Image.source was set? try to print the `source` value from `onSourceChanged` event. Anyway, just a recommendation - the right way to set image from C++ is [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of  these statements work just fine:

```
imageID.source = Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + cpplib.path + "\\3d.png")
imageID.source = Qt.resolvedUrl("file:" + "C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sli\\3d.png")
```

The problem cause was *not* the image `source` or URL format. The cause was that I was occasionally trying to show the image before the image even existed! @folibis comment guided me in the right direction.